# Singlev-variable calculus: Are all extremas turning points?

Tags: calculus, functions

I'll start off by defining two terms so that we understand each other. In my textbook,

**Stationary point** is a point $x_0$ where $f'(x_0)=0$.

**Turning point** is a point $x_0$ where the derivative $f'$ of the function changes signs from positive to negative and vice versa. For a point to be a turning point, the derivative doesn't have to exist at that point but function has to be differentiable near the point.

I know that not every stationary point is a turning point. E.g. $x^3$ has a stationary point at $x_0 =0$ but the slope ($f'$) does not change signs (it is positive in all points (excluding $x_0=0$).

And I know that no every turning point is a stationary point. E.g $f(x)= |x|$ where $f$ has a turning point at $x_0=0$ but the derivative at $x_0=0$ doesn't exist, hence why it can't be a stationary point.

There is a theorem that says that if $f$ is differentiable around the point $x_0$ and $x_0$ is a turning point, then $f$ has a pocal extrema there (depending on the change of signs we can easily determine whether it's local maximum or local minimum)

So *"If $x_0$ is a turning point then $x_0$ is a local extreme."* is true, does it work the other way around?

Is every local extreme a turning point? I can't think of a counterexample.

Comment: It is true if the function is continous at $x_0$. If it has a jump, we can easily construct counterexamples.

Comment: @Peter, can you think of any example?